# Embedding a Video in PowerPoint

Tags: html, powerpoint

Youtube provided the following code for a video I would like to embed in a presentation:

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/L6gtOVDG68g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

However, powerpoint keeps giving me the error that it "cannot insert a video from this embed code."  Is there an error in the code that youtube provided?

Answer (score 2):

Usually to embed video from YouTube into a slide, it's best to download the YouTube Wizard plug in ([here](http://skp.mvps.org/youtube.htm)). After you do that there will be an "Insert YouTube video" command on your toolbar.

However, you'd probably be better off downloading the video and embedding it from inside PowerPoint and choosing `Insert – > Movie – > Movie from file` to put the video into the current slide. That way you don't need connection to the internet.

Comment: That's helpful, but it doesn't quite answer the question of what is wrong with the code supplied by PowerPoint.